# AHBottomNavigation Not Full Width

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview

I'm switching from official Bottom Navigation View to [this](https://github.com/aurelhubert/ahbottomnavigation) library.
But I notice that when using this library, the width is not the same as the original library
Did I miss something?

Official Library:

[image: Official Library]

AHBottomNavigation:

[image: AHBOttomNavigation]

layout XML with AHBottomNavigation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.mandike.macadamia.views.MainActivity">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/mToolbarMain"
        layout="@layout/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <com.aurelhubert.ahbottomnavigation.AHBottomNavigation
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_bar_home" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/mFragmentHome"
        class="com.mandike.macadamia.views.HomeFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/mToolbarMain"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/mFragmentNotice"
        class="com.mandike.macadamia.views.AnnouncementFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/mToolbarMain"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/mFragmentMailbox"
        class="com.mandike.macadamia.views.MailboxFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/mToolbarMain"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/mFragmentMyAccount"
        class="com.mandike.macadamia.views.MyAccountFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/mToolbarMain"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        android:visibility="gone"/>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Layout XML with official library (difference is only at the library line):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.mandike.macadamia.views.MainActivity">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/mToolbarMain"
        layout="@layout/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_bar_home" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/mFragmentHome"
        class="com.mandike.macadamia.views.HomeFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/mToolbarMain"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/mFragmentNotice"
        class="com.mandike.macadamia.views.AnnouncementFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/mToolbarMain"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/mFragmentMailbox"
        class="com.mandike.macadamia.views.MailboxFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/mToolbarMain"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/mFragmentMyAccount"
        class="com.mandike.macadamia.views.MyAccountFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/mToolbarMain"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        android:visibility="gone"/>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: First of all, you are missing what we need to see. Can we see your xml and appropriate codes?

Comment: @RayHong updated my code. Sorry for not supplying the code before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found the code.
In [AHBottomNavigation.java](https://github.com/aurelhubert/ahbottomnavigation/blob/master/ahbottomnavigation/src/main/java/com/aurelhubert/ahbottomnavigation/AHBottomNavigation.java), there are some [lines](https://github.com/aurelhubert/ahbottomnavigation/blob/master/ahbottomnavigation/src/main/java/com/aurelhubert/ahbottomnavigation/AHBottomNavigation.java#L347) that change the width of each item

```
if (titleState == TitleState.ALWAYS_SHOW && items.size() > MIN_ITEMS) {
    minWidth = resources.getDimension(R.dimen.bottom_navigation_small_inactive_min_width);
    maxWidth = resources.getDimension(R.dimen.bottom_navigation_small_inactive_max_width);
}
```

Removing those lines make the bar behave like official library.

Answer (score 1):

Check **bottom_navigation_item.xml** ([link](https://github.com/aurelhubert/ahbottomnavigation/blob/master/ahbottomnavigation/src/main/res/layout/bottom_navigation_item.xml)) in the library it has padding left and right set.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/bottom_navigation_height"
    android:background="@drawable/item_background"
    android:minWidth="@dimen/bottom_navigation_min_width"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/bottom_navigation_padding_left"      // 12dp
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/bottom_navigation_padding_right">   // 12dp

    <ImageView/>

    <TextView/>

    <TextView/>

</FrameLayout>
```

If you want to change that include that library folder in your project and change the values  according to you requirement

Comment: how to add the library folder to my project?

Comment: are u taking about the same width difference that i mentioned

Comment: i think so.. I'm trying to change the padding so that I can see the difference